# How to dynamically change extrusion height of polygon in Mapbox GL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I would like to update the extrusion height of a polygon by dragging its topmost face up and down with the mouse. But I can't seem to be able to select the topmost face. Is that possible with Mapbox GL and if not, is there another framework I could use to achieve this?

Note: I am using mapboxgl in react.

Here is what I have so far, I made a handledrag function to change the hook but I don't know how I could trigger it by selecting and dragging the face of the polygon.

```
function Map() {
    const mapContainer = useRef(null);
    const map = useRef(null);
    const draw = useRef(null);
    const [extrusionHeight, setExtrusionHeight] = useState(100);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (map.current) return; 

        map.current = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: mapContainer.current,
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v11',
            center: [-46.6717, -23.5773],
            zoom: 15.59,
            pitch: 45,
            bearing: -17.6,
            antialias: true
        });

        map.current.on('style.load', () => {
            const layers = map.current.getStyle().layers;
            const labelLayerId = layers.find(
            (layer) => layer.type === 'symbol' && layer.layout['text-field']
            ).id;
             
            map.current.addLayer(
                {
                'id': 'add-3d-buildings',
                'source': 'composite',
                'source-layer': 'building',
                'filter': ['==', 'extrude', 'true'],
                'type': 'fill-extrusion',
                'minzoom': 15,
                'paint': {
                'fill-extrusion-color': '#aaa',
                
                // Use an 'interpolate' expression to
                // add a smooth transition effect to
                // the buildings as the user zooms in.
                'fill-extrusion-height': [
                'interpolate',
                ['linear'],
                ['zoom'],
                15,
                0,
                15.05,
                ['get', 'height']
                ],
                'fill-extrusion-base': [
                'interpolate',
                ['linear'],
                ['zoom'],
                15,
                0,
                15.05,
                ['get', 'min_height']
                ],
                'fill-extrusion-opacity': 0.6
                }
                },
                labelLayerId
            );
        });

        

        draw.current = new MapboxDraw({
            displayControlsDefault: false,
            controls: {
            polygon: true,
            trash: true
            },
            defaultMode: 'draw_polygon'
        });

        

        map.current.addControl(draw.current);
            
        map.current.on('draw.create', updateArea);
        map.current.on('draw.delete', updateArea);
        map.current.on('draw.update', updateArea);
            
        function updateArea(e) {
            const data = draw.current.getAll();
            const answer = document.getElementById('calculated-area');

            if (e.type === 'draw.create') {
              console.log("Create")
            } else if (e.type === 'draw.delete') {
                console.log("Delete")
            } else if (e.type === 'draw.update') {
                console.log("Update")
                const selectedFeatures = draw.current.getSelected();
                if (selectedFeatures.features.length > 0) {
                    const selectedFeature = selectedFeatures.features[0];
        
                    selectedFeature.properties['height'] = extrusionHeight;
                    draw.current.set(selectedFeatures);

                    const existingLayer = map.current.getLayer('extrusion-layer');
                    if (existingLayer) {
                        map.current.removeLayer('extrusion-layer');
                    }

                    const source = {
                        type: 'geojson',
                        data: {
                        type: 'FeatureCollection',
                        features: [selectedFeature],
                        },
                    };
                    
                    if (map.current.getSource('extrusion-source')) {
                        map.current.removeSource('extrusion-source');
                        map.current.addSource('extrusion-source', source);
                    }
                    else {
                        map.current.addSource('extrusion-source', source);
                    }

                    map.current.addLayer({
                        'id': 'extrusion-layer',
                        'type': 'fill-extrusion',
                        'source': 'extrusion-source',
                        'paint': {
                        'fill-extrusion-color': '#a5a',
                        'fill-extrusion-height': ['get', 'height'],
                        'fill-extrusion-base': ['get', 'base_height'],
                        'fill-extrusion-opacity': 0.9
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
      
            if (data.features.length <= 0) {
              answer.innerHTML = '';
              if (e.type !== 'draw.delete') alert('Click the map to draw a polygon.');
            }
        }

    });

    const handleDrag = (e, ui) => {
        setExtrusionHeight((prevHeight) => prevHeight + ui.deltaY);
      };    
    
  return (
    <div>
        <div ref={mapContainer} className="map-container" />
        <label>Extrusion Height: {extrusionHeight}</label>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Map;
```